# Delete records in SQL using the Procedure with Loop

Tags: mysql, procedure

I am trying to delete the 10 million records from DB and more with DELETE procedure of SQL. I want to delete the records in loop like with each interaction record should delete 1 like below.

```
drop procedure if exists PROC_WEEKLY_TASK_DELETE;
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `PROC_WEEKLY_TASK_DELETE`()
BEGIN

set @rows = (select count(*) from MY_TABLE where IS_VALID_DATE='false');
set @a = 0;
while(@a<@rows)
do delete from MY_TABLE where IS_VALID_DATE='false' limit 1;
set @a = (@a+1);
commit;
end while;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

I am using above procedure to delete the record but getting problem like syntax other like

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1

Please help me to create the procedure to delete the record in loop. Thanks

Comment: 10kk rows deleted one-by-one? really? You will grow old before the deletion is complete... delete by chunks, for example, 1k or 10k rows. And you don't need in rows counting - DELETE query allows LIMIT clause usage.

Comment: *but getting problem like syntax other like* What client is used for this code?

Comment: @Akina, I will change the limit to 10K or 50K

Comment: @Akina I am trying the above Procedure  , but not getting success, please guide me on it, Is it correct procedure which i am writing ,Please give me suggestion on it.. I am running on my local MYSQL

Comment: You may simplify SP till ```CREATE PROCEDURE `PROC_WEEKLY_TASK_DELETE`() BEGIN REPEAT delete from MY_TABLE where IS_VALID_DATE='false' limit 10000; UNTIL NOT ROW_COUNT() END REPEAT; END``` (deletion by 10k chunks, deletion until there is nothing to delete).

Comment: *Is it correct procedure which i am writing* No. It is possible that some rows which matches `IS_VALID_DATE='false'` will be inserted during SP execution. You fix the amount of rows to be deleted, but does not specify them. So it is possible that newly inserted rows will be deleted whereas old ones will be stored. Additional criteria (by some `created_at` column) is desirable.

Comment: @Akina Getting this problem , please check it once https://ibb.co/6Rv1qFB

Comment: Please read User Manual for your client and investigate how to create compound statements (procs, funcs and so on) in it. You try to execute the code in common query window which is obviously wrong.

Comment: People outside India aren't measuring this with "crore". Please don't use Indian words / measurements here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your all suggestions specially @Akina

Please check my new Procedure which worked for me to delete the records.

```
drop procedure if exists PROC_WEEKLY_TASK_DELETE_LIMIT;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE PROC_WEEKLY_TASK_DELETE_LIMIT()
BEGIN

repeat delete from MY_TABLE where IS_VALID_DATE = 'false' limit 10000;
until not row_count()
end repeat; 
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

> Above procedure runs successfully on local but in case of server you need to remove the *DEFINER* only